# Добавление элемента в модель

Tags: c++, qt

Не могу понять как происходит взаимодействие модели и представления.
Нужно добавить элемент в модель и установить для него виджет в отображении. У `QListView` есть метод `setIndexWidget`, который принимает индекс, но как правильно создать этот индекс?
То есть, у `QModelIndex` конструктор создает не валидный индекс, если я сначала добавлю строку, а потом возьму ее индекс, то он все равно будет не валиден:

```
int row = model->rowCount();  
model->insertRow(row);

QModelIndex index = model->index(row); // isValid() == false
```

Объясните пожалуйста как это работает

Если сильно упростить код модели, то получится что-то такое:

```
class ContactList : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ContactList(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~ContactList() {}

    int         rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant    data(const QModelIndex &index, int) const override;

    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex& parent) const override;

private:
    QVector<MyAbstractModel*> models_;
};
```

---

```
int ContactList::rowCount(const QModelIndex&) const
{
    return models_.size();
}

QVariant ContactList::data(const QModelIndex &index, int) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    return QVariant::fromValue(models_.at(index.row()));
}

QModelIndex ContactList::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if(hasIndex(row, column, parent))
        return createIndex(row, column, reinterpret_cast<void*>(models_[row]));

    return QModelIndex();
}
```

Comment: Вы сами создавали модель (класс модели)? Покажите его здесь.

Comment: @maestro приложил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема состояла в том, что метод `insertRow` вызывает внутри себя метод `insertRows`, который было необходимо переопределить. После того как я это сделал, все заработало.

```
bool ContactList::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    int end = row + count - 1;

    beginInsertRows(parent, row, end);
    for(int i = row; i < end; ++i)
        models_.append(Q_NULLPTR);
    endInsertRows();

    return true;
}
```